# Blinking led script with GPIO LEDS

Tags: python, list

I've been starting to learn Python on my raspberry pi.
I have 5 LEDs on GPIO pin 8, 10, 12, 16 and 18.

I have another code working, but I was trying to make it more compact. This one is not working but you can probably guess what I was trying to do.

I'm trying to make each led blink one by one by cycling through the `chan_list` list, but I'm stuck. How do I repeat the function for each entry of the list?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
chan_list = [8,10,12,16,18]
GPIO.setup(chan_list, GPIO.OUT, initial=0)
delay = 50
#delay = float(input("50-1000ms"))
delay = delay / 1000
led = 0
while True:
    def blink():
        GPIO.output(chan_list, 1)
        sleep(delay)
        GPIO.output(chan_list, 0)
        sleep(delay)
    blink()
```

Comment: how do you reference one of the members of a list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) function to create an iterator that will — wait for it! — *cycle* through the values is the list.

This means something like this ought to work (I can't test it). Note I also moved the definition of `blink()` out of the loop — there's no need to do it more than once.

```
from itertools import cycle  # ADDED.
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
chan_list = [8,10,12,16,18]
chan_cycler = cycle(chan_list)  # ADDED.
GPIO.setup(chan_list, GPIO.OUT, initial=0)
delay = 50
#delay = float(input("50-1000ms"))
delay = delay / 1000
delay = 1
led = 0

def blink():
    chan = next(chan_cycler)  # ADDED.
    GPIO.output(chan, GPIO.HIGH)
    sleep(delay)
    GPIO.output(chan, GPIO.LOW)
    sleep(delay)

while True:
    blink()
```

Answer (score 0):

`def blink():` should be defined near the top, not inside of a loop. The GPIO.output() function takes a single pin number as its input, not a list of pins. The same goes for GPIO.setup(). To make things a bit easier, get rid of the function. You don't need it in this specific case. You should use a `for` loop to go over each element and call GPIO.setup() on it. Then, inside of the `while` loop, you need another `for` loop which goes over each of the elements in chan_list and turns them on and off. i don't have a Raspberry Pi on me right now, but I'd bet this would get the job done:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
chan_list = [8,10,12,16,18]
for pin_number in chan_list:
    GPIO.setup(pin_number, GPIO.OUT, initial=0)
delay = 50
#delay = float(input("50-1000ms"))
delay = delay / 1000
led = 0
while True:
    for pin_number in chan_list:
        GPIO.output(pin_number, 1)
        sleep(delay)
        GPIO.output(pin_number, 0)
        sleep(delay)
```